# Set PYTHONPATH through shell script

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I am using a third party python module in my code and i need to install that module using   easy_install in my local/current directory.

I have to write a shell script which will export PYTHONPATH then do easy_install on that path ,then after executing this script i run my python script which will import that module.

However,I can not persist the PYTHONPATH set from the script after the script is done executing and hence import fails.

My script looks like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/final/dnsserver/Local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

easy_install --prefix=$HOME/final/dnsserver/Local pygeoip
```

How can I make sure that the path will be setand exported even after script is done.

P.S. I do not have root access on this machine

Comment: Have you tried sourcing the script rather than running it?

Comment: You're missing your end quote.

Comment: @Amber Could you please help with how can i source this script.I am new to it.

Comment: You'd just type `source <scriptfile>` into your shell.

Comment: That works but can i source a script inside another script?

Comment: @Amber Is there any way to set PYTHONPATH on a remote machine by sourcing a script on another machine?

Comment: `source` is a shell command. It runs the script you pass it in the environment of the current script or interactive shell, as opposed to creating a new shell environment (which is what normally happens when you invoke a script). You can run `source` on a remote machine just like you can on a local one.